# Input element in iframe can't get focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-1.8

On one of my web pages, there is an iframe that contains form elements. For some reason, these input elements don't work in the expected way:

- If a text field is clicked, it does not get focus, and typed text is not put into it.
- If the same text field has onclick="this.focus();" set, it works as expected.
- Radio buttons work as expected.
- The element containing the iframe receives the click-event as expected.
- I can't mark text in the iframe.

This does not occur in all browsers.

It occurs in:

- IE >= 9
- Firefox 18.0
- Chrome 22.0.1229.94
- Opera 12.12

It does not occur in:

- IE < 9

What happens here, and how to fix it?

**EDIT:** This seems to be a jQuery problem. It occurs when using jQuery 1.8, but not when using jQuery 1.7 (no difference between the subversions).

Comment: Do you have any script in place that may be interfering with "normal" functionality?

Comment: I think that is the problem. How would I find out, where the script interferes? I've used the Firebug debugger for hours now, and can't find anything.

Comment: The problem seems to be a jQuery problem: It occurs when using jQuery 1.8.3, but not when using jQuery 1.7.2